# postgresql: Fast way to update the latest inserted row

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to modify the latest added row without using a temporary table.
E.g. the table structure is

```
id | text | date
```

My current approach would be an insert with the postgresql specific command "returning id" so that I can update the table afterwards with

```
update myTable set date='2013-11-11' where id = lastRow
```

However I have the feeling that postgresql is not simply using the last row but is iterating through millions of entries until "id = lastRow" is found. How can i directly access the last added row?

Comment: If you have an index on the `id` column, Postgres (or any other DBMS) will not *iterate through millions of rows* - it will do an index lookup which is quite fast. But the real question is: why can't you just include that date value with the original insert statement?

Comment: Your current approach is correct and one of the fastest (if you have index on `id` field)

Comment: After testing some time i see that both versions are fast. So you can work with the "returning id" (which is postgresql specific) or with the solution i accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update myTable date='2013-11-11' where id IN(
       SELECT max(id) FROM myTable
)
```

Comment: I tested this on my database running on slow hardware with over 100.000.000 entries and it works fast

Comment: @mvb13 It will not work with concurrent inserts. You must never rely on numbers from a sequence to be ordered.

Comment: That is true. In my case it is always straight forward (insert -> maybe modify) so there is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to mvb13's answer (since I don't have enough points to comment directly yet) there is one word missing. Hopefully, this will save someone some time from working out the correct syntax LOL.

```
update myTable set date='2013-11-11' where id IN(
  SELECT max(id) FROM myTable
);
```